# Appending data from api into DOM

Tags: javascript, json, api, append

```
const url = `https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140`;

const getFact = () => {
  return fetch('https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140')
  .then(res => res.json())
}

const createFactDiv = (fact) => {
  const factContainer = document.createElement('div')
  const setup = document.createElement('p')

  setup.innerText = fact.fact

  factContainer.append(setup)

  return factContainer
}

const appendFact = (factDiv) => {
  const factContainer = document.getElementById('factContainer')
  factContainer.append(FactDiv)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

})

getFact().then ((fact) => {
  const FactDiv = createFactDiv(fact)
  append.fact (FactDiv)
})
```

I have tried several things, fairly new to JS and it is tricky. I am trying to create an app that displays cat facts. I was seeing the DIV with the FACT inside correctly in the console.log in the elements of the DOM, but now I don't see it and I keep seeing
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: append is not defined
Any idea what to do? Much appreciated !

Comment: the problem is `append.fact(FactDiv)`, the browser doesn't know what `append` is as there is no such variable. Did you mean `appendFact` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's our old friend spelling errors! Here is some working code:

```
const url = `https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140`;

const getFact = () => {
  return fetch('https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140')
  .then(res => res.json())
}

const createFactDiv = (fact) => {
  const factContainer = document.createElement('div');
  const setup = document.createElement('p');

  setup.innerText = fact.fact;

  factContainer.append(setup);

  return factContainer
}

const appendFact = (factDiv) => {
  const factContainer = document.getElementById('factContainer');
  factContainer.append(factDiv);
}

//This is unused
/*
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
})
*/

getFact().then ((fact) => {
  const factDiv = createFactDiv(fact);
  appendFact(factDiv);
})
```

This is why it's important to consistently use camelCase:

- In appendFact() you took a factDiv parameter but then tried to use FactDiv, which doesn't exist in that function
- As noted by Robin, you typed append.fact(FactDiv) instead of appendFact(FactDiv)
- This should be refactored to appendFact(factDiv) to stick with camelCase.
- Also watch your spacing, and I like to have semicolons at the end of my lines also!